# how to read scanned data from barcode scanner in .net core (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

I dont want data to be displayed in textbox or some other controls, i have to read the barcode data using USB port.

I have to create .net core application to read the barcode scanner data using .net Core.

Comment: Read the manual for the scanner.  Scanner have different modes and the drivers have different methods that can make the task easier.

Comment: It's probably going to emulate a serial port, and there will be thousands of tutorials and questions about "how to read serial port in c#"

Answer (score 0):

A barcode scanner is just a 'fast' keyboard. A application sees it as a keyboard. If you open notepad and scan a barcode you should be able to see the scanned code.

Comment: yes, it will be displayed in the notepad, but i need to read that data in .net core console application

Comment: Try this: Put `string input = Console.ReadLine();` in your code. When you do the scan, the `input` variable should contain the scanned characters.